# Getting current year in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
def bYear():
    age = input("How old are you: ")
    bYear = today.year - age
    print("Born in: " + bYear)
bYear()
```

I've started learning python a few days ago. Trying some 'stupid' stuff but I can't get this code working. 
If i try to print the year with:

```
print(today.year)
```

the output is correct.

Error message:

````
<ipython-input-1-0eeb398a7422> in <module>
      5     bYear = today.year - age
      6     print("Born in: " + bYear)
----> 7 bYear()

<ipython-input-1-0eeb398a7422> in bYear()
      3 def bYear():
      4     age = input("How old are you: ")
----> 5     bYear = today.year - age
      6     print("Born in: " + bYear)
      7 bYear()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'```

Im missing something here, any help?
````

Comment: Take a look at the other answers, some of them solve the problem. The one you gave the check to doesn't fix the second error. edit: make sure to select the one that works and explains both the problem and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because you are not changing your input type to int, and keeping it as a string, however, I do not know for sure. It would be nice if you provided your full stack trace. Try this:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
def bYear():
    age = int(input("How old are you: "))
    bYear = today.year - age
    print("Born in: " + bYear)
bYear()
```

If you instead want your code to not crash (if someone inputs something other than an integer), try this:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
def bYear():
    age = input("How old are you: ")
    if not age.isdigit():
        print("Invalid input!")
    else:
        age = int(age)
    bYear = today.year - age
    print("Born in: " + str(bYear))
bYear()
```

Comment: `bYear` will also be an int ... don’t `+` it to a string for printing ...

Comment: Correct! Thanks!
All I had to do was put int() on the input() request.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: If `bYear` is a integer (as it is), then this -> `print("Born in: " + bYear)` will raise a `TypeError` exception.

Comment: This doesn't fully solve the problem as you can't add a string and an int. Make sure you test your code before you answer a question

Comment: With the input given by Krishnan i was able to understand my error. Then coverted 'bYear' in string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your age as int as python takes input as str. And also change the bYear to str to print it using `+`.

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
def bYear():
    age = int(input("How old are you: "))
    bYear = today.year - age
    print("Born in: " + str(bYear))
bYear()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `input` it returns a string (letters). What you need is an integer. Using the `int()` function you can change strings into integers like below:

```
age = int(input("How old are you: "))
```

But wait, there's still an error! The issue is that you can only use + with things of the same type. You can't 'add' a string to an integer. To solve this use the `str()` function:

```
print("Born in: "+str(bYear))
```

So now it runs perfectly!

There is one more thing that may cause issues down the line, though. the variable `today` is not a 'global' variable, so if you make any changes to it inside of the `bYear` function, they wont carry over to the main program. To fix this put the line `global today` at the start of the `bYear` function.

Here's the full, working code:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
def bYear():
    age = int(input("How old are you: "))
    bYear = today.year - age
    print("Born in: " + str(bYear))
bYear()
```